# Return first element in SortedList in C#

Tags: c#

I have a `SortedList` in C# and I want to return the first element of the list. I tried using the "First" function but it didnt really work.

Can someone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Can you post more information, like what your list contained, what you expected to get out, what you actually got out and some sample code.

Comment: have you tried `myList.GetByIndex(0)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "*it didn't really work*"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For both [`SortedList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist.values?view=net-5.0) and [`SortedList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2.values?view=net-5.0), you can index the `Values` property:

```
SortedList listX = new SortedList();
    
listX.Add("B", "B");
listX.Add("A", "A");

MessageBox.Show(listX.Values[0]);
```

Answer (score 6):

Gordon Bell replied, but in the case you need to get the first key as well.

For the non generic collection:

```
        SortedList tmp2 = new SortedList();
        tmp2.Add("temp", true);
        tmp2.Add("a", false);
        Object mykey = tmp2.GetKey(0);
        Object myvalue = tmp2.GetByIndex(0);
```

For the generic collection:

```
        SortedList<String, Boolean> tmp = new SortedList<String, Boolean>();
        tmp.Add("temp", true);
        tmp.Add("a", false);

        String firstKey = tmp.Keys[0];
        bool firstval = tmp[firstKey];
```

Answer (score 5):

For a [non-generic SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.sortedlist?view=net-5.0), use [GetByIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.getbyindex(VS.80).aspx):

```
if (list.Count > 0)
  return list.GetByIndex(0);
```

Comment: The question is tagged generics, but your method is not available at the generic list.