# How to efficiently return the first and last item in a SortedList<> in C#?

Tags: c#, sortedlist

My question is like the following question but with `SortedList<Tkey, TValue>` instead of just the original `SortedList`.

[Return first element in SortedList in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840551/return-first-element-in-sortedlist-in-c-sharp)

There doesn't seem to be a function like `GetKey()`.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/1840655/34092 work for `First`? What index would you use for `Last` do you think?

Comment: In my opinion it'd be [.FirstOrDefault()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1065) and [.LastOrDefault()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1124)

Comment: My bad. I only read the first answer.

Comment: "There doesn't seem to be a function like GetKey()" Do you want the keys or the items?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use `list.FirstOrDefault()` and `list.LastOrDefault()`.

These two methods will return `default(KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>)` if the list is empty.

And it's better to use them because using `list.First()` and `list.Last()` will throw error in case the list was empty.

Comment: This is very inefficient as it will enumerate the whole collection to get the last item.

Answer (score 7):

According to your (not so clear) question, you want to retrieve the keys of the first and last items in the list.

`SortedList<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` so to do so:

```
sortedList.FirstOrDefault().Key
```

and

```
sortedList.LastOrDefault().Key
```

will return these keys

Edit:
As suggested by @mjwills, using the `Keys` property is a better idea in terms of performance since it implements `IList<TKey>` and `LastOrDefault` is optimized to work on such cases (not fetching the whole collection to get to the last item):

```
sortedList.Keys.FirstOrDefault()
sortedList.Keys.LastOrDefault()
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2.keys?view=netframework-4.7.2 _might_ be faster (given it is `O(1)`).

Comment: So getting `LastOrDefault` skips straight to the last one @vc74? Oh, cool. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

Using **IEnumerable<>.Last** or **IEnumerable<>.LastOrDefault** methods are efficient just for **IList<>** values. Let's look at [the source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1088) - access to the last item for not IList<> requires iterating through all items.

For more efficiency better to rely on [SortedList<>.Keys](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedList.cs#L297) or [SortedList<>.Values](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/SortedList.cs#L333) properties with type IList<> (https://dotnetfiddle.net/MLmDIL) :

```cs
        var sl = new SortedList<string, int>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
            sl.Add(i.ToString("X8"), i);
        }       

        Console.WriteLine("SortedList<> is IList<>: " + (sl is IList<KeyValuePair<string, int>>));
        Console.WriteLine("Keys-property in SortedList<> is IList<>: " + (sl.Keys is IList<string>));


        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPerformance measurement - get last Key:");

        var firstKey = sl.First().Key;

        watch.Restart();        
        var lastKey = sl.Last().Key;
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("   * Non IList<> access takes {0} (first key: {1}, last key: {2})", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, firstKey, lastKey);

        firstKey = sl.Keys.First();

        watch.Restart();        
        lastKey = sl.Keys.Last();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("   * IList<> access takes {0} (first key: {1}, last key: {2})", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, firstKey, lastKey);


        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPerformance measurement - get last Value:");

        var firstValue = sl.First().Value;

        watch.Restart();        
        var lastValue = sl.Last().Value;
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("   * Non IList<> access takes {0} (first value: {1}, last value: {2})", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, firstValue, lastValue);

        firstValue = sl.Values.First();

        watch.Restart();        
        lastValue = sl.Values.Last();
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("   * IList<> access takes {0} (first value: {1}, last value: {2})", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, firstValue, lastValue);     


        Console.WriteLine("\n\nPerformance measurement - get last Value by Key:");

        watch.Restart();        
        lastKey = sl.Keys.Last();
        lastValue = sl[lastKey];
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("   * IDictionary<> access takes {0} (last key: {1}, last value: {2})", watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, lastKey, lastValue); 

    /*
    Execution result:

SortedList<> is IList<>: False
Keys-property in SortedList<> is IList<>: True


Performance measurement - get last Key:
   * Non IList<> access takes 0.7146 (first key: 00000000, last key: 0000C34F)
   * IList<> access takes 0.0032 (first key: 00000000, last key: 0000C34F)


Performance measurement - get last Value:
   * Non IList<> access takes 0.7366 (first value: 0, last value: 49999)
   * IList<> access takes 0.0003 (first value: 0, last value: 49999)


Performance measurement - get last Value by Key:
   * IDictionary<> access takes 0.0036 (last key: 0000C34F, last value: 49999)
    */
```